# register_rest_field only for specific page

Tags: pages, rest-api

I am using register_rest_field to send an additional field to the page endpoint but it is sending it to every page. I only want it on a specific page but don't know how to pass the page id to the function.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_test' );

function register_test(){
    register_rest_field( array('page', 21),
        'recommended_test',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'get_id',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}

function get_id( $request ) {

$featured_posts = get_field('recommended');
foreach( $featured_posts as &$featured_post) {
    $featured_post->tester = get_field( 'recommended_link', $featured_post->ID );
}
    
return $featured_posts;
```

}

Comment: `register_rest_field()` doesn't support restricting the field by page/post ID. So once registered, the field will be available to all posts in the specified post type(s). But how about in the callback (`get_id()`), just return `null` or something else if the current page is not the one in question, e.g. `if ( 21 !== $request['id'] ) { return; }` ?

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I will give this a go!